# How do I start a new equation using alphabets as the new label?

Tags: equations, tags

I've set up a set of equations using numbers to show that it's the first equation, second equation etc but now I need a new set of equations that is completely unrelated to the first set and I want to use alphabets to label it instead. I tried using the code

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}}
\begin{equation}
y=x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y=x^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y=x^3
\end{equation}
```

but it just continues on to (c) and (d)

*my first set of equations had 2 equations only

Comment: What effect do you want? I don't understand your needs. Suppose you have three equations numbered (1), (2), (3). Is the number (a), (b), (c), (d), (e), (f) from the fourth equation? Or change the number of several equations temporarily. Please describe your needs clearly and say more redundant information.

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, please include a link to all other versions in each version of your question.

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/75679514/2777074

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, you're just missing a reset of the `equation` counter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
First set of equations:
\begin{align}
a & = b \\
c & = d
\end{align}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
Second set of equations:
\begin{align}
y & = x \\
y & = x^2 \\
y & = x^3
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

However, if you have more equations than just these two sets in your document, how are you going to number them? Since just using again another numbering scheme does not generalize very well to cases with more equations, I'd suggest using the `subequations` environment instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
First set of equations:
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
a & = b \\
c & = d
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

Second set of equations:
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
y & = x \\
y & = x^2 \\
y & = x^3
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```